# Blank console window opening with WinForm app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I run a windows form application, a blank console window opens up in the background while the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

A blank console window with a winform app indicates you are creating your output as a console app instead of windows app.

If you're compiling on the command line, use the switch

`/target:winexe` to create your exe

If you're using Visual Studio; under application in the project properties window, change the output type from Console Application to Windows Application.

[image: Project properties window]